# Why do I get `bus error` when calling LLVM IR function?

Tags: llvm-ir, bus-error

For this code in my language:

```
type Struct:
    x: Bool

Struct { x: true }
```

My frontend generates the following LLVM IR:

```
%Struct = type { i1 }

define %Struct @execute() {
  %1 = alloca %Struct, align 8
  %Struct.x = getelementptr inbounds %Struct, ptr %1, i32 0, i32 0
  store i1 true, ptr %Struct.x, align 1
  %2 = load %Struct, ptr %1, align 1
  ret %Struct %2
}
```

However, calling this function leads to `63069 bus error`.

But if I'll write `Struct { x: true }.x`, it will generate:

```
%Struct = type { i1 }

define i1 @execute() {
  %1 = alloca %Struct, align 8
  %Struct.x = getelementptr inbounds %Struct, ptr %1, i32 0, i32 0
  store i1 true, ptr %Struct.x, align 1
  %x = getelementptr inbounds %Struct, ptr %1, i32 0, i32 0
  %2 = load i1, ptr %x, align 1
  ret i1 %2
}
```

And this code executes correctly.

What's wrong when I return a struct?

P.S: there is a different error inside debugger
[image]

Comment: Seems like it could be related to [this llvm-16 issue](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/60432)

Answer (score 0):

The generated IR can be compiled by clang and executed without issues, hence it should be correct.

Looks like the error was caused by an internal [bug](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/60432) in `llvm 16.0`, which was used to JIT-compile and run the code